# Is there a Python script to identify which database features are in Map/Feature Services?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server

I would like to identify feature classes that are present in my map services.  Is there a way to automate this with python?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should be able to do this by unzipping the service definition file (.sd).  In the contents, there is a an xml document called "manifest.xml".  You can use the python module [xml.tree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) to read each layers name (Name tag) and its data source (OnPremisePath tag).

Here is what the manifest.xml looks like:

[image]

you can unzip files with this function:

```
import os
import zipfile

def unzip(z, new):
    zfile = zipfile.ZipFile(z)
    for name in zfile.namelist():
        (dirname, filename) = os.path.split(name)
        if not os.path.exists(new):
            os.makedirs(new)
        zfile.extract(name, new)
```

Comment: Hi do you have an example of this?

Comment: I don't have any examples using xml.tree readily available, but I do know that module is pretty straightforward to use. I did edit my response to add some code for how to unzip a file.  Honestly, I think the easiest way would be to just loop through the mxd that was used to create the service if you know where those are.

Comment: that defeats the purpose of the script to loop through the MXD, say if the MXD was deleted, or overwritten, I just need to know the DB sources of each feature service.  Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the REST endpoint of the Map Service:

```
import urllib2
import json

content = urllib2.urlopen("http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/USA/MapServer/layers?f=pjson").read()
service = json.loads(content)

for layer in service['layers']:
    print layer['name'], ":", layer['type']
```

Or use [ConvertWebMapToMapDocument (arcpy.mapping)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s30000006n000000) to get an MXD and [List Layers](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s30000002n000000) in a more familiar way.